# Ejabbed audio/video call is not working on different network

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I am using ejabberd for chat and audio/video and implemented from the following URL
https://www.process-one.net/blog/how-to-set-up-ejabberd-video-voice-calling/

Audio-video calling is working in the same network but when both android app using different networks then the call is connecting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly configure listener ports of TURN STURN server and give the public ip
question is where is public ip comes from firstly you need to configure your own TURN sever or you can purchase that if you configure your own server this is you can do
[Setup up your own TRUN server](https://medium.com/av-transcode/what-is-webrtc-and-how-to-setup-stun-turn-server-for-webrtc-communication-63314728b9d0)

deploy this server and  use this ipv4 ip in your ejabberd listener config
This is my STUN/TURN configuration in ejabberd.yml:

```
 port: 3478
 transport: udp
 use_turn: true
 turn_ip: "212.83.142.6"
 auth_type: user
 auth_realm: "im.silverpeas.net"
 module: ejabberd_stun
```

- port: 3478
  use_turn: true
  turn_ip: "212.83.142.6"
  auth_type: user
  auth_realm: "im.silverpeas.net"
  module: ejabberd_stun